# how to reset() form to specific value reactively in angular 7

Tags: angular, methods, reset

my .ts file to do this is:

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      genders = ['male', 'female'];
      signupForm: FormGroup;


      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}


      toSubmit(){
        console.log(this.signupForm); 
        this.signupForm.reset(this.signupForm.controls.userData.value.username = 'ahmad');
        console.log(this.signupForm.controls.userData.value.username);

      };
```

But it does'nt work and the value of username stay null.

Comment: You'd better use `setValue` (patchValue will loop on your form until it finds the control). `this.signupForm.get('userData').setValue('ahmad')`

Answer (score 1):

you should use `this.signupForm.patchValue({username = 'ahmad'});` instead of reset

Comment: but it can't find username like this!

Comment: Please explain why the OP should use that - he should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benefit of the future readers.